# 'try' for 'duration' in python 3

Tags: python, time, outlook

I am figuring out how to have my python try to complete an action ( that may never be able to happen ) until what is the equivalent of a timer runs out in which case it runs a separate function.

The exact scenario is bypassing the "Warning" screen that outlook provides when something of an automation system tries accessing it. When the initial command is sent to retrieve data from or otherwise manipulate outlook the entire python script just stops and waits ( as best as I can tell ) waiting for the user to click "Allow" on the outlook program before it will continue. What I'd like to happen is that upon it trying to do the manipulation of outlook there be a timer that starts. If the timer reaches X value, skip that command that was sent to outlook and do a different set of actions.

I feel that this may lead into something called "Threading" in order to have simultaneous processes running but I also feel that I may be over complicating the concept. If I were to do a mockup of what I think may be written to accomplish this, this is what I'd come up with...

```
time1 = time.clock()
try:
    mail = inbox.Items[0].Sender
except if time1 > time1+10:
    outlookWarningFunc()
```

I am 99.9% sure that "except" isn't ever used in such a manner hence why it isn't a functional piece of code but it was the closest thing I could think of to at least convey what I am trying to get to.

I appreciate your time. Thank you.

Comment: You could just use a while loop and wrap the while loop in a try/except clause to catch anything

Comment: @PeterWang, I thought the same thing when I approached this issue. The problem is that once the command "mail = inbox.Items[0].Sender" is hit, the entire process stops moving forward. No subsequent commands fire off hence my theory of needing threading. I am currently researching that as a solution for now. Thank  you for the thought though, I appreciate it! :)

Comment: This isn't a `try/except` block because Outlook application isn't actually raising any error, it's waiting for user input through a modal dialog box.

Comment: @ToddLewden what's the warning/msg that Outlook (might) display, and which you're trying to circumvent?

Comment: @DavidZemens , I believe you are correct. The 'code' I wrote is not at all functional or usable. I will be updating this shortly with a more accurate representation of the code I am trying to make. I believe Threading is the way I need to go.

Comment: Cheers, yes I was more or less responding to Peter's comment. a `while` loop would work if Outlook was raising an error, but it's not. :)

Comment: @DavidZemens , http://pasteboard.co/6BNAeSwYY.png , that's the warning message that comes up. It doesn't report anything back to Python to reply to from what I understand hence my concept of just timing it then sending clicks/keystrokes via pyautogui to get rid of it then retry the manipulation commands. I am sorry if this is confusing in any sense... I will do my best to clarify if needed.

Comment: No, it makes perfect sense I am just trying to see if there is some other option or setting you can configure or query which wouldn't raise that message.

Comment: `blocking`, `timeout`, and `select` are the terms that you're looking for. You need some more code to make it a [mcve], but in general you want to be able to select on this action with a timeout

Comment: Can you also explain what you expect the main codeline to be doing during the wait?  *nothing continues moving forward*, from your comment on w's answer, makes me think you *don't* just want to wait. **try, while-trying-main, after-timeout-fail and on-success** are your flows, but you didnt cover #2.  On the other hand, if all you want is a timeout, then be exlicit about that.

Comment: @JLPeyret, In this circumstance for the sake of keeping it simple I am just having the 'main code' retrieve the sender's name, that's all. As it stands when that snippit runs the warning message comes up and everything halts. In order to get the warning message to come up I have to try to manipulate something in outlook. Once I manipulate something in outlook the warning comes up and the program waits for manual input of the user to "Allow" python to mess with outlook. It's a bit of a catch 22 in my opinion. I hope this clarifies things for you. Thank you for taking the time to comment.

Answer (score 4):

One of the solutions is this:

```
import threading

mail = None

def func():
    global mail
    mail = inbox.Items[0].Sender

thread = threading.Thread(target=func)
thread.start()

thread.join(timeout=10)
if thread.is_alive():
    # operation not completed
    outlookWarningFunc()
    # you must do cleanup here and stop the thread
```

You start a new thread which performs the operation and wait 10 seconds for it until it completes or the time is out. Then, you check if job is done. If the thread is alive, it means that the task was not completed yet.

The pitfall of this solution is that the thread is still running in the background, so you must do cleanup actions which allows the thread to complete or raise an exception.

Comment: Hello, I implemented your suggested code ( thank you for putting such time into helping! ) but it appears to have the same result as if I were using a "While" statement. The thread is kicked off and mail = inbox.Items[0].Sender goes, the window pops up on Outlook but nothing continues moving forward. The timeout is just 10 seconds and I waited 20 on my tests of it. Do you think I am "Up a creek" as it were? :P

Comment: The code is executing forward because, as I said, thread is still running (window pops up and doesn't close). Even if the time is up, thread is not killed, but your script goes further asynchronously (you can put `print` just after if statement to test it). It's actually really hard to kill a separate thread. You should use some function to force close the window from the script inside the if statement.